# upload image using image Path in flask

Tags: python, flask, imgur

I want to upload an image file to `imgur` using the python-Flask. So for this I am submitting an image file from the form and want to upload this file to imgur.

But the point is the example snippets given in the imgur api want the path name of the file that was uploaded. So far I was trying to upload but I am stuck!!

This is my `main.py` file

```
if request.method == "POST":
    image = request.files.get('myfile') #myfile is name of input tag 
    config ={
            'album':album,
            'name':'Catastrophe!',
            'title':'Catastrophe!'
    }
    print os.path.realpath(image.filename) # this line gives me wrong path of file.
    print "uploading image..."
    #image = client.upload_from_path(filepath,config=config,anon=False)
```

The commented print statement gives me path like this

> /home/suraj/Desktop/FlaskTrials/wallpaper.jpg

But the thing is the correct file path could be anything the user wants to choose image from

How do I get this path. Am I doing the right thing to upload the image to imgur api ?

I would be able to do by making an dir in root folder and adding image to it and then get the filename of that and upload to imgur.

But I was wandering is it possible without saving and image file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you forgot to save the file on the server. Here is a modified version of your code based on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    image = request.files['myfile'] #myfile is name of input tag
    config ={
            'album':album,
            'name':'Catastrophe!',
            'title':'Catastrophe!'
    }
    print "uploading image..."
    filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join('/home/suraj/Pictures', filename))
    print os.path.realpath(image.filename)
```

I recommend considering restricting the file names to certain extensions, as suggested by the Flask doc.